# Run python in a html template while iterating though a list

Tags: django, django-templates

```
def ViewCharges(request):
    account = get_object_or_404(StripeAccount, team_members=request.user)
    payment_requests = PaymentRequest.objects.filter(company=account).order_by('-created')
    return render(request, 'dashboard/charges.html',{'payment_requests':payment_requests})
```

This is how my template looks after doing

```
               {% for request in payment_requests %}
                      <tr>

                        <td>{{ request.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ request.email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ request.amount }}</td>
                        <td>{{ request.paid }}</td>
                        <td><a href="/dashboard/charges/{{ request.pk }}" class='btn btn-dark btn-sm'>Manage</a></td>

                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
```

And in my models, I store the paid field in pence (e.g 100 = £1), this is for stripe. And I can properly format it by doing

```
real_amount =  "{:.2f}".format(amount / 100)
```

this works fine until I need to do it in a for loop in html, is there a way I can do this in the html doc

```
                  <tr>

                    <td>Bob</td>
                    <td>Bob@example.com</td>
                    <td>£20</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td><a href="/dashboard/charges/3523" class='btn btn-dark btn-sm'>Manage</a></td>

                  </tr>
```

The rest is fine I just need some help with that formatting, does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You want to get the value of `real_amount` in your template?

Comment: Yes, I want to put the real_amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property on your models to calculate `real_amount`. Then you can access this property in your HTML template or anywhere else just like any other field attribute of your model.

Example:

```
class MyModel(...):
    ...

    @property
    def real_amount(self):
        return "{:.2f}".format(self.amount / 100)
```

Then in your templates:

```
{{ request.real_amount }}
```